# Using an Angular library (APF) inside a Firestore cloud function

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I created a angular library using angular 14 inside a workspace, added a class with a method, now I'm trying to use it inside the functions folder using typescript, the workspace structure is as follows:

```
root
   dist
      my-lib
         ...
   functions
      ...
   projects
     my-lib
     my-app
```

After building the library, I tried using it inside the helloWorld cloud function like this:

In functions/tsconfig.json under compiler options, added `"paths": {"my-lib": ["../dist/my-lib"]}`.

And functions/package.json, added a dependency: `"my-lib": "file:../dist/my-lib"`,

and then in `functions/src/index.ts`: `import {MyClass} from "my-lib";`.

Problem: when starting the emulator 'firebase emulators:start --only functions' I get this error:

```
Error: Failed to load function definition from source: Failed to generate manifest from function source: Error [ERR_REQUIRE_ESM]: require() of ES Module C:\angularproject\dist\my-lib\fesm2015\my-lib.mjs not supported.
Instead change the require of C:\angularproject\dist\my-lib\fesm2015\my-lib.mjs to a dynamic import() which is available in all CommonJS modules.
```

What's the correct way to include a library from an Angular project in a firebase cloud function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to get this to work by changing the following:

`functions/tsconfig.json`

```
"module": "es2020",
"target": "es2020",
"moduleResolution": "node",
```

and in `functions/package.json` added

```
"type": "module",
```

Now I can run the emulator without an issue.